# Why doesn't my calendar view show added events - something wrong with my CAML?

Tags: list-view, calendar, provider-hosted-app

My code is pretty straight forward. I create a Calendar list and some views for the calendar.

I create one view for each contact in my custom contact list (containing a "User" field which contains that person's login username).

All of this is created when I start my **provider hosted app**.

The thing is that when I add a calendar event I should be able to see that event in my view. In my custom calendar user field I have added my username "Developer" in my case. (see picture)

[image]

```
     Uri hostWeb = new Uri(Request.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);

        using (var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetS2SClientContextWithWindowsIdentity(hostWeb, Request.LogonUserIdentity))
        {
            Web web = clientContext.Web;
            ListCreationInformation listCreator = new ListCreationInformation();
            listCreator.Title = "CompanyCalendar";
            listCreator.Description = "Workcalendar";
            listCreator.TemplateType = (int)ListTemplateType.Events;

            List ifListExcists;
            // ValidateList() is a custom method to validate if the list already excists
            if (!ValidateList(clientContext, listCreator.Title, out ifListExcists))
            {
                List calList = web.Lists.Add(listCreator);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                testLabel.Text = "The " + listCreator.Title + " list was created";

                //Get my custom contactlist that contains a User field that contains the login username of that contact
                List contactList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Contacts");
                CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection collection = contactList.GetItems(query);
                clientContext.Load(collection);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                foreach (var thisPerson in collection)
                {
                    //Find the username for this user in cantactlist
                    var loggedInUserName = thisPerson["loggedInUser"];

                    //Get the internal name for LastName field (Which is the only Required field in this list) in the contactlist just for testing
                    string currentUserName = thisPerson["Title"].ToString();

                    //Create a new CalendarView
                    ViewCreationInformation newView = new ViewCreationInformation();
                    newView.Title = currentUserName;
                    //Show events that a re "created by"(Author) thisPerson["loggedInUser"]
                    newView.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' /><Value Type='User'>" + loggedInUserName + "</Value></Eq></Where>";

                    calList.Views.Add(newView);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                //I don't think I need this but I post it just to show that its still not working even though I try to update the views.
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ViewCollection viewCollection = web.Lists.GetByTitle("CompanyCalendar").Views;
                clientContext.Load(viewCollection);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.View view in viewCollection)
                {
                    view.Update();
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                }
                testLabel.Text = "List already excist";
            }
        }
```

This shows after I add an event logged in as "Developer" (which is the username inside "Bergsten"-view).

[image]

**My Question:**
Why doesn't this view show the events that I'm adding? They do show in default the calendar view but not this "Bergsten"-view. The CAML filtering doesn't seems to work. Is there something that I'm missing or is it something wrong with my view.Query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try like this:

```
var loggedInUserName = thisPerson["loggedInUser"] as Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue;
int userId = loggedInUserName.LookupId;

//Create a new CalendarView
ViewCreationInformation newView = new ViewCreationInformation();

//Show events that are "created by"(Author) thisPerson["loggedInUser"]
newView.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' LookupId='TRUE' /><Value Type='Lookup'>" + userId + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
```

This should work..

Comment: Thank you!
This line worked:
newView.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' LookupId='TRUE' /><Value Type='Lookup'>" + userId + "</Value></Eq></Where>"